# VirtualBox error "Failed to open a session for the virtual machine"

Tags: virtualbox

I have a virtual machine with Windows XP with a clean installation. I set it as immutable to create a differential machine, so I create a new virtual machine, select the immutable hard disk and create a new snapshot in the new virtual machine folder.

However, when I try to start the virtual machine I get this error:

```
"failed to open a session for the virtual machine".

Código Resultado: 
VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80BB0007)
Componente: 
ProgressProxy
Interfaz: 
IProgress {c20238e4-3221-4d3f-8891-81ce92d9f913}
```

What is the problem? until now I can use differential virtual machines without problems. I have installed the last version or VirtualBox v4.3.4 and the problem persists.

If I set the hard driver as normal and I create a new virtual machine and select this hard drive I don't have any problem.

EDIT: I use the same virtual disk and do the same steps in another computer and it works fine. I think that the problem is the VirtualBox of my computer with the problem, but I try to uninstall the program and reinstall it and the problem persists, so I don't know how to solve the problem.

EDIT 2: if I set the virtual harddrive as multiattached instead of immutable, then it works fine. In my case is enough, but I know that it would be work as immutable because it was work until now and it works in another computer.

I try to create a new user in windows to try if the problem if with the configuration of my account, but the problem persists. So I think that some general configuration of VirtualBox has been corrupted and I am not be able to repair it.

I would like to know if there is any solution to use a immutable hard drive, because I would like to solve the problem with VirtualBox, although by the moment the multiattached hard disk is enough.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem when restoring a saved machine. I wonder if your issue and mine might be the same [as this bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11938). It is probably a good idea to search through other VB bug tickets to see if there is a better match (my problem, and that ticket, is about restoring a saved machine, not starting a new one).

Comment: Whilst this is a good question, I am going to see if it can be moved to _SuperUser_ - this site is for programming questions. Thanks.

Comment: I asked a mod for this to be moved, but it was declined as it is too old. You may get answers here, but please ask future questions of this kind on the correct site. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

I had the same issue, I tried editing the VM but it wasn't letting me save it. So I tried the following:

1. Tried editing the VM to change RAM/CPU etc, but it wasn't letting me save it
2. Deleted the vm (not the data) and tried adding it again, didn't fix it
3. Tried moving the vbox file to another directory and import it, but it didn't let me move the vbox file so I realized there's a virtualbox process running that's holding a lock on it. So I killed that process and started it again and my VM booted

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it - open task manager, kill virtual box process and it runs just fine

Comment: You just saved my life!

Comment: It was an old VBOX process running which was causing this issue. The MacBook had crashed once (Xcode does it sometimes on highSierra) and on restart it probably restarted the old VBOX process which was not in good state.

Answer (score 17):

Killing VM process dint work in my case.

Right click on the VM and click on "Discard Saved State".

[image: Right click on the VM and click on "Discard Saved State".]

This worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

For windows users
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

I had the same issue, and this trick works for me

1. Goto control panel
2. Open Uninstall program
3. Click on turn windows features on or off
4. Scroll down and find the hyper-V folder.
5. Uncheck the Hyper-V.
6. Apply changes and restart your system.
7. Now here you go... Open your virtual  box and start the os you want.

Hope this helps..

Comment: I do not have such folder.

Comment: You could use either docker or VM

Answer (score 6):

Updating VirtualBox to newest version fixed my issue.

Comment: Yes fixed my issue after updating to 5.2 version

Comment: v6.1 same issue

Answer (score 2):

If you are in Windows and the error message shows `VT-x is not available` make sure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows components.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it is caused by privilege, please try this:

```
#sudo chmod 755 /Applications 
#sudo chmod 755 /Applications/Virtualbox.app
```

Comment: Note that the `#` is not part of the command (otherwise it will get commented out =P)

Answer (score 1):

Something that I tried and work for me is simply you create a new virtual machine and you use the existing virtual hard disk file and everything is like you left it.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, this can also be caused by incorrect permissions. I `chmod 755 Logs/` which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I gave administrator privilege to Virtualbox and it solved my problem.
i.e., run `run as administrator` on windows 10

Answer (score 1):

In may case, "VM VirtualBox Extension Pack" was broken. So I uninstalled it and reinstalled it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sepehr - I found the same item to be true.  Upgraded VBox 6.32 to 6.36 and was asked to update VboxExtPack.  The VboxExt pack failed to install [network error] Subsequently downloading the updated ExtPack separately and installing worked..  Must add, I had to reinstall vbox 6.36 as well.

Answer (score 0):

**For MAC users**

After some research, this worked for me:

- Quit VirtualBox
- Right click "Applications" folder
- Click on "Get Info"
- Change "Everyone" Permission to "Read Only"
- Open VirtualBox, and now it should work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally this error occurs when it try to load the previous state. This happened in Mac Virtual box. 
I tried after restarting the virtual box but again also i've encountered this issue.
Right Click on the operating system in the virtual box and then Click on the **Discard Saved State..** .This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key
```

and restart your system, when restart it shows option and select Mok key and you will work fine.

Comment: sudo: update-secureboot-policy: command not found

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that solved the issue for me is to unmount the second hard disk on my laptop.
My current setup contains 1 HDD on SATA0 port and 1 SSD on SATA1 port. I've the OS and Oracle VirtualBox installed on the SSD drive.
When I deleted the partition on the HDD, the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

1. open a cmd with admin privilige
2. bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
3. reboot

Error gone and VMs are working again.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. In the Oracle VM Manager - right click on your virtual maching (for example kali linux).
2. In the menu choose "discard saved state".
   Then press discard and restart your virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu based system, solution that worked for me...

Delete virtualbox and download the latest deb package from the virtualbox website.